# Angular + Laravel + UI-Router Issue

Tags: angularjs, laravel, routes, angular-ui-router

I am creating a SPA using AngularJS, Laravel, and UI-Router. Within the Laravel routes.php file, I have a single route '/' that loads index.php, which is where all my dependencies are included and where angular gets bootstrapped. As a child of the angular rootscope, I have a div with the "ui-view" attribute. This div is where my Angular templates are loaded using UI-Router.

Within my angular module .config, I have a few UI-Router states setup:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

// Routes config using ui-router

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', 
    {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })

    .state('projects', 
    {
        url: '/projects',
        templateUrl: 'templates/projects/index.html',
        controller: 'ProjectController'
    })
    .state('projects.create', 
    {
        url: '/projects/create',
        templateUrl: 'templates/projects/create.html',
        controller: 'ProjectController'
    });
}]);
```

The issue I am having is that when I load the third state, "projects.create", the browser does not bootstrap angular with my js/app.js main module. It fires off an error: "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once".

But it works fine when I load the "projects" state. Also, by testing I realized that if I change my "projects.create" state URL to "/createproject", instead of "/projects/create", and this fixed the issue.

I presume that this is a path interference issue when trying to load "js/app.js" and other local dependencies. How would I go about resolving this so the apps dependency URL's are dynamic to UI-Router States?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>AngularJS App</title>

        <!--css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

</head>

<body ng-app="scynergyApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view>

        </div>


    </div>
</body>
<!--js-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--angular core-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>


        <!--angular controllers-->
        <script src="/js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/controllers/ProjectController.js"></script>
</html>
```

Routes.php

```
<?php
// =============================================
// HOME PAGE ===================================
// =============================================
Route::get('/', function(){
return View::make('index');
});

// =============================================
// API ROUTES ==================================
// =============================================
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'/api'),function(){
    Route::post('login','AuthController@Login');
    Route::get('logout','AuthController@Logout');

    Route::resource('projects','ProjectsController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit',       'update')));
});

// =============================================
// CATCH ALL ROUTE =============================
// =============================================
// all routes that are not home or api will be redirected to the frontend
// this allows angular to route them
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

Comment: Paste your routes.php file.

Comment: Joseph - I have added routes.php to the question

Comment: @Austin : Why did you include the CDN and the actual file also at the same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `projects.create` state maps to the `templates/projects/create.html` url.

It seems that you do not have that template available, so it falls into your catch-all `App::missing`, which renders the whole page again.

When loading the page again, you're also running all of its linked resources again, so you're trying to run angular again. Angular detects this, and barks.

Just make sure you have that template file at the specified URL, and all will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response Joseph. You are absolutely right - I did a quick test and changed the URL to "../templates/projects/create.html" and it loaded my template. I didn't realize that the templateURL was relative to the state URL. In the case of best practices, is there a better method of structuring my app so I am not using relative links in the templateURL? Thank you again, Joseph!

Comment: @Austin - Use a `base` tag in your HTML.